# Async await compile error on WP 7.5 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-await

I am not able to compile this simple code:

XAML:

```
xmlns:live="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Live.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Live.Controls"

        <live:SignInButton 
            Name="SkydriveSignInButton" 
            ClientId="xxxxx" 
            Scopes="wl.skydrive_update wl.offline_access wl.basic wl.signin" 
            Branding="Skydrive" 
            TextType="SignIn" 
            SessionChanged="SkydriveSignInButton_OnSessionChanged" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
        />
```

C#:

```
    private void SkydriveSignInButton_OnSessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);

            ListFiles();
        }
        else
        {
            client = null;
        }
    }

    public async static void ListFiles()
    {
        LiveOperationResult operationResultGA = await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");
    }
```

The error is: Cannot await 'void'

The project is in VS2010 with Bcl.Async and Live 5.4 packets installed

Comment: You really need to use VS2012 for `async`/`await` development. What you're trying to get working is some combination of the Async CTP and `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, and that's not going to end well...

Comment: @StephenCleary No, it won't work on WP7 because the library doesn't support Task returning methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler is right - you cannot `await` `void` :D

You can only await `Task` and `Task<T>` types (and those with custom awaiters) but definitely not `void`.

The problematic method `GetAsync`, where does it come from? From Live SDK? I don't think that you can await those, you need to build a wrapper around it. You have GetCompleted event for that.

Also, change the return type for `ListFiles` method from `void` to `Task`.
And change the caller code to:

```
await ListFiles();
```

Don't forget to add async to that method to. As a rule, remember to never write `async void` unless it is an event handler. It's `async` all the way down :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i forgot to state that code works as is in VS2012 in a WP8 project, i'm unable to let it work in WP7...

Comment: Like I said, you cannot `await` those, you need to use `GetCompleted` event. You can create your own `GetTaskAsync` method which will wrap over the event.

Answer (score 0):

The Live SDK package is not depending on Bcl.Async so for WP7 it cannot be using Task (WP8 support Task by default so there is no dependency needed for that version).

You can easily create your own async Task method like this:

```
public static class MyLveExtensionAsync
{
    public static Task<LiveOperationResult> GetResponseAsync(this LiveConnectClient client, string param)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<LiveOperationResult> tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<LiveOperationResult>();
            EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;
            handler=(sender, arg) =>
            {
                client.GetCompleted -= handler;
                if (arg.Cancelled)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                }
                else if (arg.Error != null)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetException(arg.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    LiveOperationResult result =new LiveOperationResult(arg.Result,arg.RawResult);
                    tcs.TrySetResult(result);
                }
            };

            client.GetCompleted += handler;
             client.GetAsync(param);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

}
```

That you can use like this:

```
LiveOperationResult operationResultGA = await client.GetResponseAsync("me/skydrive/files");
```